# Restore files in git repo without commit

Tags: git, github

I created a Git repo and a remote on Github. In project folder i made `git init` and forgotten made first  `git commit`. After i made git pull from remote repository and all my files in local folder disappeared. I tried

```
git reset --hard origin/master
git reset --hard
git checkout <filename>
git checkout -f master
```

but it didn't help me. Everywhere write that need restore last commit but i don't have his.

How i can restore all my files?

Comment: So the files in the local folder were never commited?

Comment: Yes. Was only git init. Maybe me help remove .git folder?

Comment: Can you do a git reflog -all and show its output

Comment: @thewhitelakeofhimalayas `fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not very clear if you committed before `git pull` or not. It's also not clear how the files got wiped out, because Git would ask you first, unless you used one of the forcing flags.

Anyway, if you committed your files at some point, then they are probably not lost. Are you sure you don't have them on any branch? Check this first:

```
git log --graph --decorate --all --oneline
```

If you don't see your commits, then you can try to recover deleted files with:

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

The output may look something like this:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
dangling blob 058a46ad6fec7b6ee95710eb06daa0b8169a5da0
dangling blob f1d509348c7689f0f127d9eba5324db8221d5603
```

Notice the dangling blobs. They are deleted files. You can see their content with `git show SHA1`, or you can find those files in `.git/lost-found/other/`.

On the other hand, if you have never committed or staged your original files, then they are completely gone. If you never told about them to Git, then it doesn't know about them, and therefore cannot recover using Git.

Comment: Can i restore these dangling blob objects or i can watch only their content?

Comment: @Giffo you can copy the files from `.git/lost-found/other`, or redirect the output of `git show`, and do whatever you want with them.

Comment: dude, this saved my life :))